# Should I write "in the region" or "across the region"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions

What would be correct to use in this statement, "in" or "across"?

> Responsible for strategic direction and management of all sales and service operations **in** the region.

or

> Responsible for strategic direction and management of all sales and service operations **across** the region.

Comment: Did the company have multiple regions, each with a head of region?

Comment: Yes, 4 regions (NA, Latin America, Europe and Asia), each with a head of region.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I'd answer this based on the size of the company. Is the company national/international? If so, I'd go with "in the region", because it is more accurate.

Is it a local company with multiple branches located in the same city (region)? If so, then "across the region" might sound more appropriate (letting the employee know the job responsibility includes the entire region rather than a mere portion).

Answer (score 0):

Since there are specific regions, you could also use the preposition **for**:

Responsible for strategic direction and management of sales for the X region.

or

Responsible for strategic direction and management of sales for X [where X is the name of the region].